# Access values in an externally generated array

Tags: c, nidaqmx, daq-mx

I am taking voltage readings and converting them into pressure readings. This is my first real experience with C so my code is messy but so far has worked fine. The problem I am facing is making the program count the number of readings (stored in the array data[i]) that fall between a min and max desired value.

Here is the code, Sum2 and count are the areas giving me trouble. Sum2 is adding 999 values instead of filtering and count is always resulting in 998 when it should be closer to 500

EDIT:

the readings in data[i] are voltage and I am working with pressure. My calibration curve is P=(V-2.9674)/.404

```
    //Voltage readings for NI USB-6009 built from the ground up

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "NIDAQmx.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "tdmwriter.h"
#include "fundtypes.h"
#include "platdefines.h"



#define DAQmxErrChk(functionCall) if( DAQmxFailed(error=(functionCall)) ) goto Error; else

int main(void)
{
    int32       error = 0;
    TaskHandle  taskHandle = 0;
    int32       read;
    float64     data[1000], Sum=0, Average, Variance, Deviation=0, std_dev, min=0, max=0, num=0, avg=0, minP=0, maxP=0, avgP=0, avgP2=0, minP2=0, maxP2=0, minV=0, maxV=0, avgV=0, Sum2 = 0;
    char        errBuff[2048] = { '\0' };
    int         i, count = 0;

    /*********************************************/
    // DAQmx Configure Code
    /*********************************************/
    DAQmxErrChk(DAQmxCreateTask("Pressure Voltage\n", &taskHandle));
    DAQmxErrChk(DAQmxCreateAIVoltageChan(taskHandle, "Dev1/ai0", "", DAQmx_Val_Cfg_Default, -10.0, 10.0, DAQmx_Val_Volts, NULL));
    DAQmxErrChk(DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming(taskHandle, "", 100.0, DAQmx_Val_Rising, DAQmx_Val_FiniteSamps, 1000));

    /*********************************************/
    // DAQmx TDMS Configure Code
    /*********************************************/
    DAQmxErrChk(DAQmxConfigureLogging(taskHandle, "C:\\TestData\\LogFile.tdms", DAQmx_Val_LogAndRead, "ECS Test Data", DAQmx_Val_OpenOrCreate));
    //DAQmxWriteAnalogF64(taskHandle,1000, 1 /*autoStart*/, -1 /*timeout*/, DAQmx_Val_GroupByScanNumber, data, 1000, NULL);

    /*********************************************/
    // DAQmx Start Code
    /*********************************************/
    DAQmxErrChk(DAQmxStartTask(taskHandle));
    printf("Voltage due to Pressure:\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Recording Data...\n");
    DAQmxErrChk(DAQmxWaitUntilTaskDone(taskHandle, 10.0));


    /*********************************************/
    // DAQmx Read Code
    /*********************************************/
    DAQmxErrChk(DAQmxReadAnalogF64(taskHandle, 1000, 10.0, DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel, data, 1000, &read, NULL));

    printf("Acquired %d points\n", (int)read);


    /*********************************************/
    //Display Values
    /*********************************************/
    printf("\n");
    printf("values:\n");
    printf("Voltage 1= %f\n",data[10]);
    printf("Voltage 2= %f\n", data[100]);
    printf("Voltage 3= %f\n", data[200]);
    printf("Voltage 4= %f\n", data[300]);
    printf("Voltage 5= %f\n", data[400]);
    printf("Voltage 6= %f\n", data[500]);
    printf("Voltage 7= %f\n", data[600]);
    printf("Voltage 8= %f\n", data[700]);
    printf("Voltage 9= %f\n", data[800]);
    printf("Voltage 10= %f\n", data[900]);
    printf("\n");

    //for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    //  printf("Voltage %i= %f\n",i, data[i]);
    //}
    //printf("\n");

    /*********************************************/
    //Average Values
    /*********************************************/
    for (i = 1; i < 999; ++i) {
        Sum = Sum + data[i];
    }

    Average = (Sum / 999);
    printf("Average= %f\n", Average);


    /*********************************************/
    //Standard Deviation
    /*********************************************/
    for (i = 1; i < 999; ++i) {
        Deviation = Deviation + pow((Average - data[i]), 2);
    }

    Variance = Deviation / 999;
    printf("Variance= %f\n", Variance);

    std_dev = sqrt(Variance);
    printf("Standard Deviation= %f\n", std_dev);

    printf("\n");


    /*********************************************/
    //Min and Max Values
    /*********************************************/

    {
        max = fmax(data[2], data[999]);
    }
    {
        min = fmin(data[2], data[999]);
    }

    printf("Min: %f\n", min);
    printf("Max: %f\n", max);
    printf("Log File located in C:\\TestData. Please rename LogFile.tdms after testing\n");
    printf("\n");


    /*********************************************/
    //Convert to Pressure Readings
    /*********************************************/
    printf("Pressure Readings (inches H2O):\n");
    {
        minP = (min - 2.9674) / .404;
        maxP = (max - 2.9674) / .404;
        avgP = (Average - 2.9674) / .404;
    }
    printf("Min Pressure: %f\n", minP);
    printf("Max Pressure: %f\n", maxP);
    printf("Average Pressure: %f\n", avgP);
    printf("\n");


    /*********************************************/
    //New Voltage and Pressure Averages
    /*********************************************/
    {//target min and max pressure
        minP2 = avgP - (avgP / 10);
        maxP2 = avgP + (avgP / 10);
    }
    {//target min and max voltage
        minV = (minP2*.404) + 2.9674;
        maxV = (maxP2*.404) + 2.9674;
    }
    {//Sum of values in desired range
        for (i = 1; i < 999; ++i) {
            if (minV < data[i] && data[i] < maxV); { Sum2 = Sum2 + data[i]; }
    }
    }
    {//Number of values in desired range
        for (i = 1; i < 999; i++)
        {
            if (minV < data[i] && data[i] < maxV);
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    {//New average voltage
        avgV = Sum2 / count;
    }
    {//New average pressure
        avgP2 = ((avgV - 2.9674) / .404);
    }
    printf("Adjusted Values:\n");
    printf("Min P2= %f\n", minP2);
    printf("Max P2= %f\n", maxP2);
    printf("Min Voltage= %f\n", minV);
    printf("Max Voltage= %f\n", maxV);
    printf("Sum Voltage= %f\n", Sum2);
    printf("Count= %d\n", count);
    printf("AvgV= %f\n", avgV);
    printf("AvgP= %f\n", avgP2);


Error:
    if (DAQmxFailed(error))
        DAQmxGetExtendedErrorInfo(errBuff, 2048);
    if (taskHandle != 0) 
    {
        /*********************************************/
        // DAQmx Stop Code
        /*********************************************/

        DAQmxStopTask(taskHandle);
        DAQmxClearTask(taskHandle);
    }

    if (DAQmxFailed(error))
        printf("DAQmx Error: %s\n", errBuff);
    printf("End of program, press Enter key to quit...\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation to make it more readable.You also have brackets that are not required. Make sure to use spaces and not tabs.

Answer (score 0):

C is zero based index so you have been skipping the first value every time, which may or may not give a bad value. The extra brackets caused you to miss setting up the conditional correctly. I marked the bad ; with a comment so you can see it.

```
sum2 = 0; // not needed since initialized above
count = 0; // not needed since initialized above
for (i = 0; i < 999; ++i) 
{
    if ((minV < data[i]) && (data[i] < maxV)) // ; messed up and forced code to execute
    // Extra parens are just for readability
    {
        //Sum of values in desired range
        Sum2 += data[i];
        //Number of values in desired range
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an erroneous `;` after the following lines

```
if (minV < data[i] && data[i] < maxV);
```

and

```
if (minV < data[i] && data[i] < maxV);
```

These cause the following code block to be always executed, since the `;` creates a "do-nothing" code block.

**EDIT:** are you also doing the wrong calculation for `minV` and `maxV`? What do they have to do with pressure?

```
minV = (minP2*.404) + 2.9674;
maxV = (maxP2*.404) + 2.9674;
```

Perhaps that puts the data out of their range, since the loop fails to catch any values.

Comment: Removing the ';' results in a count and sum of Zero

Comment: In that case something else is wong, as well. As you said, "Sum2 is adding 999 values instead of filtering" and this was why.

Comment: Perhaps it is because you fiddle with `minV` and `maxV` before testing the data against them.

Comment: @NikMif I have added more to my answer.

Comment: `minV = (minP2*.404) + 2.9674;
maxV = (maxP2*.404) + 2.9674;` Is the conversion from pressure to voltage. The data begins in voltage and must be processed at pressure

Comment: Well either they are outside the range, or the data isn't what you expected it to be.